# How to print char**

Tags: arrays, c

I have a variable

```
char **data;
```

and I'm trying to print the content of the variable. I understand it to be array of arrays. How would I print it?

Thanks

Comment: It's not array of arrays, it's pointer to pointer. Pointers =/= arrays

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do it, depending on exactly what you want.  If `data` is a collection of strings, perhaps you just want `for( int i ; ...) printf("%s\n", data[i];)`, but you need to know how to properly set the bounds for the loop, and you haven't provided enough information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a `pointer to a pointer` not array of arrays

You need use `**data` to get value

- `data` will give the memory address which `data` variable holds
- `*data` will give the memory address of the pointer whose address `data` is holding
- `**data` will give you the actual value

Say you have a variable like

```
char c = 'X';
char *cp = &c; //cp stores memory address of c
char **cpp = &cp; //now cpp is pointer which points to a existing pointer cp
```

To get the value stored at the location which pointer points to - we need to `dereference` the pointer.

```
printf("%c", *cp); //prints 'X' 
printf("%p", *cpp); //prints memory address of cp 
printf("%c", **cpp); //prints 'X' (double stars because address->address->value)
```